# The support of a Radon measure given by a continuous density function

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

On a Hausdorff space $X$ we are given a non-negative Radon measure $\mu$. We are also given a continuous function $f:X\to[0,\infty)$. We are interested in the measure $\sigma=f d\mu$. (i.e. $\sigma(A)=\int_A f d\mu$)

I have proven that $\sigma$ is a non-negative Radon measure on $X$.

I want to prove that the support of $\sigma$ equals the intersection of the support of $f$ and the support of $\mu$.
I think I have proven one inclusion: $\mathrm{supp}\sigma\subseteq \mathrm{supp}f\cap\mathrm{supp}\mu$.

But I have difficulties with the other inclusion. Anyone has an idea of how to prove it?

UPDATE

I found out that the inclusion I was trying to prove is actually wrong: For a counterexample, take $X=\mathbb{R},\: f(x)=x^2,\: \mu=\delta_0$ (i.e. the Dirac measure with pointmass $1$ at $0$.)

Then $\mathrm{supp}f=\overline{\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}}=\mathbb{R}$ and
$\mathrm{supp}\mu=\{0\}$, so $\mathrm{supp}f\cap\mathrm{supp}\mu=\{0\}$.

But $\sigma(x)=x^2d\delta_0(x)$ is the zero measure, so $\mathrm{supp}\sigma=\emptyset$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $g$ is a positive function on $X$ and supp$g \subset \text{supp}f \cap \text{supp}\mu$. Then supp$(f\cdot g) \cap \text{supp}\mu \neq \emptyset$, and $h\colon = f \cdot g$ is a positive function. As $h$ is a positive function with supp$h \cap $supp$\mu \neq \emptyset$, we have that $\int_X gd\sigma = \int_X h d\mu > 0$. Thus, we have that $\text{supp}\sigma \supset \text{supp}f \cap \text{supp}\mu$.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer Oles :)
However I don't see how the conclusion follows from $\int_Xgd\sigma>0$. From that it follows that $\mathrm{supp}g\cap\mathrm{supp}\sigma\ne\emptyset$.

But don't we need $\mathrm{supp}g\subset\mathrm{supp}\sigma$ in order to conclude $\mathrm{supp}\sigma\supset\mathrm{supp}f\cap\mathrm{supp}\mu$?

Comment: As $g$ was chosen arbitrarily, I showed that any positive function supported in the intersection, integrates positively over the new measure $\sigma$, and hence supp$f \cap$supp$\mu \subset$supp$\sigma$

Comment: Thanks again. Still I am not sure how the argument works. Could you please provide more details?  
Normally when proving a set-inclusion we take an element in one set and prove that it is also an element in the other. But you take a function supported on one set and proves its support intersects the other set. I don't see what's the idea behind the proof.  
Maybe there is a lemma/result or something I am not familiar with? I have just worked with the defintion $x\in\mathrm{supp}\mu$ if and only if $\mu(V)>0$ for all open $V\ni x$.

Comment: Using this definition we get that
$x\in\mathrm{supp}f\cap\mathrm{supp}\mu$ if and ony if$x\in\mathrm{supp}1_Vf\cap\mathrm{supp}\mu$ for all open $V\ni x$ which implies that $\mathrm{supp}1_Vf\cap\mathrm{supp}\mu\ne\emptyset$ for all $V\ni x$.
Is this equivalent with $\sigma(V)=\int_Vfd\mu>0$ for all open $V\ni x$? And if so, how to prove it?

The last statement is equivalent with $x\in\mathrm{supp}\sigma$.

I am sorry for the many questions. I am quite new to the subject and want to learn it thoroughly. Thanks for your time.

Comment: The thing is the following. Measures can be seen as a function from some $\sigma$-algebra into the complex numbers satisfying some conditions, or equivalently, can be seen a functionals on the space of continuous and compactly supported functions. Thus for me, there is no difference between taking some subset $U\subset X$ or singleton $x\in  X$, and a positive function supported in the subset/singleton. I hope this helps.

Comment: Once one has a functional, you can get a regular measure back, by taking characteristic functions of sets.